# What exactly does open source mean?

Tags: updates, open-source

I have heard that Ubuntu is an open source OS, which i think means people can edit the code. I've heard this makes it safer because multiple people are trying to fix insecurities in the programming. But doesn't that mean that people could also break this code. Could people actively access my pc? Are these changes approved by Canonical? Please help I know I sound stupid but its because I'm new to all this.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?  Or do you want to know this to improve your general knowledge?

Comment: @user68186 I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and it would be nice to improve generally knowledge if needed.

Comment: People can download/copy the code and edit/change their copy.  Do think if they wanted to add their edits to Canonical's copy for people to use, it would have to be reviewed and tested.  A person would probably need hands on access to your pc to change any of the code.

Comment: You can get a great introduction and primer using the Search Engine question: "*What is Open Source software?*"

Comment: They can also change their copy, call it Linux I Made, and offer it for people to download and use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open source means many things, but it starts with a simple definition which I'm going to quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source):

> Open source is a source code that is made freely available for possible modification and redistribution.

That's a really simplified definition and it is a bit more complicated.

For the most part, everything is open source - meaning that you have the freedom to request the code so that you may modify it. But, doing so comes with some responsibilities.

Much of what is included in Ubuntu is covered by the [GPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License). So, if you modify the code *and then distribute it* you must also grant those same rights to other people, thus ensuring the freedom of the code to be modified by other people.

Some open source licences (of which there are [many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_free_and_open-source_software_licences)) are more (or less) permissive. The 'more or less' is often decided by the person evaluating the license as they may prioritize different freedoms.

So, in this case, you're free to download, alter, and redistribute [most of **?**] the code. When you redistribute it, you too become obligated to uphold the freedoms of the open source license chosen by the original author(s).

It's really quite a bit more nuanced, but that's the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

With open source, everything — the code, and the collaboration of people to produce that code — is out in the open. Whoever wants to check it, can see it. The idea is, if someone tries to sneak something in, they get caught quickly, thanks to the large number of peers working on or with the project. [This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124658/is-open-source-software-vulnerable-to-viruses?rq=1) discusses this in more detail.

**Linux kernel**

[kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/) has the [Linux kernel source code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/).

**Further, installable packages**

Package result pages on https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages and https://packages.ubuntu.com/ usually contain links to the source of each package.

**GNOME Project (desktop environment and applications)**

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME shows all source code and allows [insights](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/activity) into the collaboration.

**Masters of the Universe**

Use this site's search bar, and search the term: "masters of the universe".

"Universe" is a package repository for Ubuntu. Masters of the Universe are people who carry out various aspects of quality assurance for these packages.

Sort by relevance. Read more then one thread, follow links, read up on things mentioned in those threads. It will give you a picture on how quality assurance works in this context.

**Personal Package Archives**

[What are PPAs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343333/whats-the-difference-between-a-ppa-and-a-repository)

[about PPA security](https://askubuntu.com/q/53221/1157519)

**Trust and vigilance**

And yes, in the end, one needs a degree of trust towards the ecosystem.

The more you use it, the more signs of professionalism you encounter. That makes it easier.

But that does not mean that one should let one's guards down entirely. Before installing something new and novel, some poking-around and critical thinking is advised.